# "I was wondering what time it is" or "I was wondering what the time has been"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, verb-agreement, present-perfect, simple-past

Can you tell me which option is more natural in this English sentence?

> I'm sorry to trouble you but I was wondering what
>
> (A) time it is
>   (B) the time has been

---

The whole story is that this multiple-choice question comes from a placement test for a coursebook. The complete question is as follows

> I’m sorry to trouble you but I was wondering what
>
> (A) time it is
>   (B) the time has been
>   (C) is the time?
>   (D) was the time?

I excluded (C) and (D) as ungrammatical and chose (A) as the most natural-sounding to me, but the answer key says that the correct answer is (B), which doesn't sound right to me. Now I'm a little bit confused.

This coursebook is for the Polish market and I am Polish.

Comment: Well, one asks about the past, and one the present. What do you want to know about?

Comment: NO! (B) What the time has been is the *least* acceptable of the lot.  If you just want to know the time of day, (A) is what natives would say. (C) might be what somebody trying to sound pretentious might say, (D) might be said when reviewing a past event and trying to figure out what time it was when the event took place.  and (B) might only make sense in the most bizarre set of contrived circumstances.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I have only recently stopped to believe in answer keys :-) ; I mean, I now try to view all the answers as possible constructions of events and that's why your explanation convinces me. Thank you.

Comment: @Jim: Do you really think native speakers would say ‘I'm sorry to trouble you but I was wondering what time it is’?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: it certainly sounds totally natural to me; obviously much better than any of the other answers on the OP's test, but also more natural than your proposed "...what the time is". Of course, what a native speaker is *really* most likely to say is "What time is it?", without the contrivedly-polite preface.

Comment: @ynglisz: was the question maybe asking you to choose the option that is *not* correct? That's the only scenario where "B" would be the correct answer.

Comment: @BarrieEngland- Without a doubt.  This might be the most typical phrasing in the States.  Other phrasings might be, "Could you please tell me what it is?" or "Do you know what time it is?" Of course the latter may be answered by simply "Yes." but it is still quite a common turn of phrase.

Comment: @Jim: Perhaps another case of AmE v. BrE then. For me, it would be _I was wondering what the time was_.

Comment: I know it's odd because of the mixed tenses but of the 4 options, (A) sounds the most natural to my AmE ear.

Comment: @Marthaª: No, the question was asking to choose the option that IS CORRECT, and the key suggested B as the only answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking the time, (A) is closer to what a native speaker might say, but it would be more likely to occur as *. . . what the time is*. However, because the first part of the sentence contains the past tense *was*, the second part would probably also be in the past tense: *. . . what the time **was***.